# Silverlight bouncing ball using double animation

Tags: silverlight, animation

Just wondering if anyone has any guidance on making a ball continuously bounce around inside a box (4 walls), changing direction after hitting a wall and using DoubleAnimations so that it can be hardware accelerated. I've found code for moving a ball by setting its canvas X Y coordinates but it's quite slow.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample application for pinball.  They have bouncing off of bumpers but gives a good example with decent performance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2009/11/30/9896181.aspx